# Can't click on views

Tags: android, android-layout

I don't know how to explain this other than I cannot click on anything in the android studio designer. I can edit the xml fine, but I am trying to use constraint layouts and its easier if I can drag and drop things. When I hover over anything the hand pointer does not appear and the attributes don't show up if I click. I think it has something to do with floobits but I'm not sure. Floobits just seems sort of buggy to me. Just wanted to post to see if others have had the same problem or for someone to hopefully point out something obvious I have missed. I have opened another project and that works perfectly fine. Thanks.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: just tebuild your project or invalidate cache and restart

Answer (score 0):

Clean Project -> then Rebuild project -> then restart Android studio